# Mantaflow fluid bake at high quality?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I have been using Blender's fluid physics for a while now, and I have been wondering if it is actually possible to do a fluid bake at 1024 quality. What would this look like, and how could I achieve it?

How about in Blender 2.82+ mantaflow? What would a 1500 quality fluid bake + mesh bake look like, and how much memory would be required to run it?

Comment: AFAIK, the built-in fluid solver is an implementation of [SPH](https://cg.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/publications/2014_EG_SPH_STAR.pdf) fluids which theoretically is a nice algorithm but due to its complexity quite slow. In addition to that, the implementation in blender is neither multithreaded nor optimized. It would take ages. I suggest better go with FLIP instead, which is basically a more balanced approach between speed and quality at the moment. Sidenote: I've personally never seen any good looking sph sims. Also I don't think blender has any option to solve white water or even spray.

Comment: I know there are better fluid simulators you can add to Blender, but I am wondering if you can use Blender's built-in fluid simulator at 1024. Using HP's Z8 G4 with 2 28-core platinum CPUs with 1.5tb of ram would it still take a while?

Comment: You didn't get my point. *In other words:* Even if you had access to an bigger machine or even hundreds of them, it's just a waste of time and energy using blender for fluids, because it *can't neither handle multiple cores nor 1.5tb+ ram* for the actual calculation. And again, you definitely want whitewater, spray or bubbles for quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not depends only on the resolution... If you are using a big domain compared to world space, the slower the simulation, the smaller time step is required, the faster the simulation is. The simulation speed divides when you double the resolution, and it will consume x^3 ram. This means if you bake 2x2x1.5m cube with 256res, it uses 3,6GB of ram. 1024 will require extreme amount of ram, somewhere hundreds of gigs. And it will be BRUTAL slow. it will take 37 days with a ryzen 5 1600x cpu.

Comment: Thank you for the information.